# How Can We Study the Possibility of Uniform "Distribuitons" on Countable Sets Like $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

I wonder if there exist ways to deal with infinitely coutable sets with a probability in the  "uniform" sense. In the basic Probability Theory, as far as I know, we usually study **two kinds of probability** most of the time that is compatible with our sense of probability:

1- First one is **the discrete probability** which uses **convergent sums** and **mass functions** defined on a finite outcome space $\Omega$ and finite $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F} \subset 2^{\Omega}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$. We consider $\sigma$-algebras to generalize the concept but things are simpler here and all can be induced to positive sums and series.

- In this version, **uniform distributions** corresponds to the case that the mass function is constant and $f({x}) = 1/n$ for each outcome $x\in\Omega$ where $|\Omega| = n$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is just the entire power set $2^{\Omega}$ since it should contain all singletons and all sets are finite. Then, for any event $E\in \mathcal{F} = 2^{\Omega}$ where $|F| = k \leq n$, it produces $f(E) = k/n$ by finite additivity of the (probability) measure.
- Other than the uniform distribution, we can consider any **countable** $\Omega$ where $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$ is still satisfied which means that any non-negative function $f$ satisfying $\sum_{x\in \Omega} \mathbb{P}({x}) = 1$ can be considered as a mass function. Then, **the sense for uniform distribution does not work here as a probability mass function** because countable infinite set causes the mass function $f(x)$ to be zero if $E$ is finite or undefined caused by indeterminate quotient $\infty/\infty$ if $E$ is infinite.

2- However, there is the second kind of the theory, **the continuous probability** on, for example, real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ using **Lebesgue Integration**. In this case, probability is not considered as the sum of singleton outcomes, i.e. $\sum f(x)$, but the **integral of the density function** of an event $E\in \mathcal{F}\subset 2^{\Omega}$ as the integral $\int_E fd\lambda$ in general. So we can use the similar set-up here where the only change is to use integration instead of sums and series.

- Now the **sense for uniform density** here is just a **constant function** again: Given a bounded measurable set E which is not null, e. g. intervals. Then $c := m(E) \in (0, \infty)$ and we can use the **uniform distribution** on this bounded set as $f(x) = 1/c > 0$. Then we simply have the total probability as the integral $\int_E f dm = (1/c)c = 1$ which makes it a distribution for real.
- **Unfortunately, there are things we are missing here, too**: None of the **null sets** are covered by the continous probability as well as sets with **measure $\infty$**:
- The latter is similar to the problem we encountered in discrete case since **it causes the uniform distribution on the set to be 0** and then the probibility, which means the integral of the zero distribution here, ****becomes 0, not 1**.** On the other hand the former is caused by the fact that **integrals over null sets are zero automatically, not 1**. Thus no function $f$ can be a density function for a null set like countable infinite sets $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ if they are null in the given measure, for example **Lebesgue Measure** or **Borel measure**.
- Finally, I think that using a measure where the set $\mathbb{N}$ is
  not null (consider a measure where every natural number is an
  **atom** that of equal measure) **coincides with the discrete probability** with some editing since the integration
  on $\mathbb{N}$ becomes the limit of the finite sum by the definition
  of the integral via simple functions.

**QUESTION**: We have the sense that **choosing a random natural number should be considered in some sort of "uniform" way**. ***How can we describe that uniformity and study it in a natural sense? Which tools do we have to examine them?***
After my surfing on that topic I realized that the discrete way cannot handle some of infinite quantities includig uniform ones and continous way cannot handle null-sets including countable ones. So I believe that there should be a middle-way or a completely different approach to study (infinitely) countable uniformity.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150734/discussion-on-question-by-alileo-how-can-we-study-the-possibility-of-uniform-di); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find a paper by Bumby and Ellentuck on 'Finitely-additive Measures and the First Digit Problem' worth looking at. Bumby has slides [here](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ebumby/Measures.pdf) giving a some-years-later review of that paper and some of the followup. This is at least one approach to the problem you're thinking about.

As a small side-remark, I know about this paper because when I was an undergraduate in the 1970s, I wondered the same thing, and my professor suggested I look at this paper --- so this is apparently a question that keeps arising over the years. As I recall, I actually called up and spoke to one of the authors, who said that the original manuscript of the paper used non-standard analysis, but the reviewers rejected it on that basis, so they had to unwind the definitions to write the eventually-accepted version. That explains the presence of all that stuff about ultrafilters, etc.

Comment: That's a great first-hand feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may work with **improper uniform distributions** commonly used in Bayesian statistics.

It is a way of defining a uniform prior density $f$ for a parameter with a value in $\Omega$, which can be $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb R$. The density is defined as $f(x)=c, x \in \Omega$ for some positive (undefined) constant $c$.

This violates the law of probability for $\Omega=\mathbb N$ or
$\Omega=\mathbb R$ because this distribution does not have a finite sum.

For **an improper prior distribution**, it does not sum to 1: either the sum is a finite value unequal to 1 or cannot be normalized to sum to 1.

The intresting point is that this method, which violates the probabilty law, may result in **proper posterior distributions.**